# Powerdot shrink text in figure caption

Tags: floats, captions, lyx, presentations, powerdot

I am using the powerdot class to make my first presentation in LaTeX (LyX). I have a figure whose caption contains a lot of text. Currently the text rolls off the slide. I can manually change the font size, but I'd like powerdot to shrink the text to fit. I have seen that beamer has a similar option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could use the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package for typesetting captions with a certain width, such as by

  ```
  \captionsetup{width=\textwidth}
  ```

  So the caption would be wrapped at the right margin and continued on the next line. This should be better than scaling the font size, which can result in a hardly consistent design.
- If scaling is really needed, it can be done using `\resizebox` of the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package.

Answer (score 1):

use package `caption` with a smaller text font:

```
\documentclass{powerdot}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{slide}{foo}
\begin{figure}
\rule{0.5\textwidth}{3cm}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\end{slide}

\end{document}
```